# Visual Studio 2012 loading debug DLLs from wrong directory, but only for WebMatrix 3 projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, webmatrix, freeze

I use VS2012 and WebMatrix 3.  I use VS2012 for a lot of other work besides WebMatrix 3.  For the longest time everything was fine and I could open WebMatrix 3 solutions in VS2012 and debug them.  A few days ago I could no longer do that.  However, I can debug all my other projects including Windows Phone, ASP.NET, Desktop, etc. without any problems.  Only WebMatrix 3 generated projects are causing trouble.

When I debug a WebMatrix 3 project now the IDE hangs for a long time, several minutes.  Then it lands on my first break point and I see a dialog box saying:

"Loading symbols for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll from:
C:\WINDOWS\dll
Attempting to cancel will disable further symbol loading."

However, the DLL it is trying to load is not always the same name, but it's always an indigenous DLL like the one above, so it's not a DLL I created that VS2012 is having trouble loading. The problem is "C:\WINDOWS\dll" does not exist on my hard disk.  I am wondering at this point if it's treating each DLL like a typical download and the long wait is due to a URI time-out (pure speculation here)?

If I return back to the IDE it immediately becomes unresponsive again with the app window title showing the "Not Responding" message.  After a similar wait it comes back again and this cycle repeats until I kill the IDE using the Task Manager.

Why is VS2012 having trouble finding DLLs only with WebMatrix 3 projects and not with others?

How can I fix this?